# jooq connection is null error when attempting to insert multiple records at once

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I'm trying to insert multiple records into mysql db using jooq 3.18 and getting the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because the return value of "org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.connection()" is null

    at org.jooq_3.18.2.MYSQL.debug(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using r2dbc driver and here is what my query looks like:

```
fun create(tags: List<String>){
val tags = tags.map {
                 val record = dsl.newRecord(TAGS)
                 record.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                 record.userId = "dc5f0fbf-7979-4bcd-9f99-c3261a8d2ffe"
                 record.tag = it
                 record
             }.toList()

             dsl.batchInsert(tags)
                 .executeAsync()
                 .await()
}
```

jooq config class:

```
@Configuration
class JooqConfig(val cf: ConnectionFactory) {

    @Bean
    fun jooqDslContext (): DSLContext{
        return DSL.using(cf).dsl()
    }
}
```

Inserting a single record is working fine but getting the error on batch insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ should probably throw a better exception in this case. I've created an issue for this:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15331

In any case, as of jOOQ 3.18, all `*Async` methods returning a `CompletionStage` run on JDBC and block behind the scenes. There is not yet an R2DBC implementation that returns a `CompletionStage`. R2DBC is a reactive driver API, not an asynchronous one, so you can't use these methods.

As of jOOQ 3.18, you can't yet use batch CRUD with R2DBC, i.e. this also doesn't work:

```kotlin
dsl.batchInsert(tags).await()
```

This is because of the following limitation:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/14874

But you can run a bulk `INSERT` statement instead:

```kotlin
dsl.insertInto(TAGS)
   .columns(TAGS.ID, TAGS.USER_ID, TAGS.TAG)
   .valuesOfRecords(tags)
   .await()
```